# RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, runtime-error

I've loved using this site for little tips on code, and I try to solve all the errors I can by myself. However, this one has had me stumped for days. I just can't crack it.

RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
    at flash.text::TextField/setTextFormat()
    at BibleProgram_fla::MainTimeline/checkAgainstBible()
    at BibleProgram_fla::MainTimeline/compileInputString()
    at BibleProgram_fla::MainTimeline/spaceBuild()

```
function spaceBuild(event:Event):void //This program runs every frame
{
    compileInputString();
}

function compileInputString():void
{
    inputVerse = inputText.text; // takes text from the input field

    inputVerse = inputVerse.toLowerCase();
    inputVerse = inputVerse.replace(rexWhiteSpace, "");  //Removes spaces and line breaks
    inputVerse = inputVerse.replace(rexPunc, ""); // Removes punctuation

    inputVerse = addSpaces(inputVerse); //adds spaces back in to match the BibleVerse
    inputVerse = addCaps(inputVerse); //adds capitalization to match the BibleVerse
    checkAgainstBible();
}

function checkAgainstBible()
{
    outputText.text = inputVerse; // sets output text to be formatted to show which letters are wrong

    for(var n:Number = 0; n < inputText.length; n++)
    {
        var specLetter:String = inputVerse.charAt(n);

        if(specLetter != bibleVerse.charAt(n))
        {
            outputText.setTextFormat(red, n); // sets all of the wrong letters to red
        }

    }
}
```

Whenever I run the program and type a string longer than the BibleVerse, it returns the error, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

I hope I provided enough information for you to help me. If you need more code or something, please ask!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would get that error if n is greater than the number of characters in the outputText when it sets its format color to red, and it looks like your outputText's characters are extended or shortened when you make it equal to your inputVerse because inputVerse had all the regex operations that i can't seen done to it. So most likely these operations are shortening the characters and so outputText.text is shorter than it should be and when it loops over the inputText.length, when it gets to the end of the outputText, n goes past its character length and so you get that error (That is what the error is - you are attempting to access something that is not there). So the way i see it is (using example made up strings);

```
// Pseudo code...
inputVerse=inputText.text; // (lets say its "Thee ")
// inputVerse and inputText.text now both have 5 characters
inputVerse=lotsOfOperations(inputVerse);
// inputVerse now only has 4 characters (got rid of the " " at the end)
outputText.text=inputVerse;
// outputText.text now has the new 4 character
for(var n:Number = 0; n < inputText.length; n++)
// loops through inputText.length (so it loops 5 times)
outputText.setTextFormat(red, n);
// if n=4 (since n starts at 0) from the inputText.length, then when it access
//outputText.setTextFormat(red,n) it is accessing a character of outputText.text
//that is at the end and not there. outputText.text is too short for the loop.
```

So, your problem is that your operations to inputVerse are making it too short to compare to the other strings, I don't know your other code so I can't say whats wrong, but this is why you are getting the error. Please comment if you have any questions or to notify me of what I am missing.

Comment: Was going to contest this but after re-reading it makes sense. Couldn't he fix this by checking `for (var n:Number = 0; n < inputVerse.length; n++)` since **inputVerse** (or even outputText) contains the final expected length after all that regExp editing? Another thing that could help him is changing `for(var n:Number = 1;` since it's unlikely he would be checking an empty (0) textfield? I'm no expert though just learning by looking at challenging questions.

Comment: Well looping with inputVerse or the outputText.text instead would get rid of the error, and maybe that is what he mean to do in the beginning, i don't know. And i'm not sure how making n=1 for the first iteration would help, since it would still go to n=4 and cause the error. Hopefully he responds to my answer so that you can really  learn what was wrong and what not to do in the future. Because learning by this example is easier than learning by encountering this problem in your own code.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I think I will implement both of these. You guys make me feel so stupid sometimes. I really love StackOverflow for that reason.

Comment: @timo352 ..Feel free to up vote either my comment or answer as "useful" if it helped out a bit. Xiler still keeps the correct answer this way.

Comment: @Xiler ..You're right about the n=1. What I was thinking? (or maybe not thinking?? haha). I'm gunna up vote your comment because you taught me something today with your answers. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. :(Just two more!

Comment: Its ok, dont worry about it - as long as you got accepted the answer because it works, and you did that, then its cool. Good luck with your bible application, im exited to see the final product.